# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Portal site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4 and please bear with me. I am building a  portal where users will be shown different widgets. Lets just say widgets are some rectangular boxes with a title and a content. What would be a better way to implement this? i am planning to use partial views. And then call Html.renderaction on the aggregate view. Is this a good choice or is there a better way to do it?

2.)Also when the widget encounters any exception i would like to show a custom error message just on the widget area. I dont want the entire page to be redirected to an error page. Just the rectangle area alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.RenderAction` should do the work, for the exceptions a try/catch can help you:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Widget(int id) {
    try
    {
      var widget = Repository.GetWidget(id);
      return PartialView(widget);
    }
    catch
    {
      return PartialView("WidgetErrorPage");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
In that case you can use an `ActionFilter` to handle the exceptions, like explained here  [Return View from ActionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507536/return-view-from-actionfilter) or here [Returning a view with it's model from an ActionFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669553/returning-a-view-with-its-model-from-an-actionfilterattribute):

```
public class WidGetHandleException : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "WidgetErrorPage",
                ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
                TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData,
            };
        }
    }
```

And then decorate all your widget actions like this:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
 [WidGetHandleException]
 public ActionResult Widget() 
 {

 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead of doing in every action is there a centralized way to do that exception handling and redirecting?

Comment: I assume you will use just one Action to render all widgets based on an id, you can also set the custom errors like explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553922/custom-asp-net-mvc-404-error-page but im not sure that will help you in this case, AFAIK that will render a full page error not a partial page.

Comment: I have many widgets. My site is primarily composed of widgets only. So i will have a lot of action methods for those widgets

Comment: Updated answer with `ActionFilter` alternative